# Does Tweepy support running multiple Streams to collect data?

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, tweepy

For example, I'd like to collect data related to three keywords:

1. keyword1
2. keyword2
3. keyword3

I understand that I could collect them all at one time using: `set track=[keyword1,keyword2,keyword3]`.  Is it possible to run three different Python processes to collect data for those keywords separately?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, [no](https://twittercommunity.com/t/streaming-api-only-one-standing-connection-per-account/7120). Assuming you're using Tweepy's `Stream` class (which uses the Twitter Streaming API) you can not make multiple connections with a single account. You should also watch out if you try to circumvent this using multiple accounts:

> Each account may create only one standing connection to the public endpoints, and connecting to a public stream more than once with the same account credentials will cause the oldest connection to be disconnected.
>
> Clients which make excessive connection attempts (both successful and unsuccessful) run the risk of having their IP automatically banned.

-[Twitter Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/public)

Comment: Thanks,@Luigi.Do you mean that if I use three different accounts to collect data separately,I'll face the risk of being IP-blocked ? If so ,then it's not recommended ?

Comment: If you do it on the same ip you do run that risk. Definitely not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, you have to create a separate Listener class per stream

Comment: That's a comment, it's not an answer... read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Aside from this not being an answer, it's also an incorrect statement.