# How can I dynamically change the type of tweets that are being streamed and figure out which message to send to who?

Tags: python, twitter, rabbitmq, tornado, tweepy

## App Description

So I'm trying to create an application that does real-time sentiment analysis on tweets(as close to real time as I'm able to get it) and these tweets have to be based on user input. So in the main page of my application, I have a simple search bar where the user can enter a topic they would like to perform sentiment analysis on and when they press enter, it would take them to another page where they see a line chart displaying all the data in real time.

## Problem 1

The first problem I'm facing at the moment is that I don't know how I can get tweepy to change what it is tracking when two or more people make a request. If I were to have global streaming that I simply disconnect and reconnect every time the user makes a new query, then it is also going to disconnect for other users as well which I don't want. On the other hand, if I were to allocate a streaming object for each user that connects, then this strategy should work. This still poses a problem. Twitter does not allow you to hold more than one connection at a time it seems given this StackOverflow post.

[Does Tweepy support running multiple Streams to collect data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477915/does-tweepy-support-running-multiple-streams-to-collect-data/26493454)

If I still were to go along with this, I risk getting my IP banned. So both of these solutions are no good.

## Problem 2

The last problem I'm having is figuring out who the message belongs to. At the moment, I'm using RabbitMQ to store all incoming messages in one single queue called `twitter_topic_feed`. For every tweet that I receive from tweepy, I publish it in that queue. Then RabbiMQ consumes the message and sends it to every available connection. Obviously, that behaviour is not what I'm looking for. Consider two users who search for pizza and sports. Both users will receive tweets pertaining to football and pizza when one user asked for sports tweets and the other asked for pizza tweets.

One idea is to create a queue with a unique identifier for each available connection. The identifier would have the form **{Search Term}_{Hash ID}**.
For generating the hash ID, I can use the UUID package that is available in python and create the ID when the connection opens and delete it when it closes. Of course, when they close the connection I also need to delete the queue. I'm not sure how well this solution would scale. If we were to have 10,000 connections, we would have 10,000 queues and each queue could potentially have a lot of messages stored in it. Seems like it would be very memory intensive.

## Design

- `tornado Framework` for WebSockets,
- `tweepy API` for streaming tweets
- `RabbitMQ` For publishing messages to the queue whenever tweepy receives a new tweet. RabbitMQ will then consume that message and send it to the WebSocket.

## Attempt(What I currently have so far)

`TweetStreamListener` uses the tweepy API to listen for tweets based on the user's input. Whatever tweet it gets, it calculates the polarity of that tweet and publishes it to rabbitMQ `twitter_topic_feed` queue.

```
import logging
from tweepy import StreamListener, OAuthHandler, Stream, API
from sentiment_analyzer import calculate_polarity_score
from constants import SETTINGS

auth = OAuthHandler(
    SETTINGS["TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_KEY"], SETTINGS["TWITTER_CONSUMER_API_SECRET_KEY"])

auth.set_access_token(
    SETTINGS["TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY"], SETTINGS["TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY"])

api = API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


class TweetStreamListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self):
        self.api = api
        self.stream = Stream(auth=self.api.auth, listener=self)

    def start_listening(self):
        pass

    def on_status(self, status):
        if not hasattr(status, 'retweeted_status'):
            polarity = calculate_polarity_score(status.text)

            message = {
                'polarity': polarity,
                'timestamp': status.created_at
            }

            # TODO(Luis) Need to figure who to send this message to.
            logging.debug("Message received from Twitter: {0}".format(message))

    # limit handling
    def on_limit(self, status):
        logging.info(
            'Limit threshold exceeded. Status code: {0}'.format(status))

    def on_timeout(self, status):
        logging.error('Stream disconnected. continuing...')
        return True  # Don't kill the stream

    """
    Summary: Callback that executes for any error that may occur. Whenever we get a 420 Error code, we simply
    stop streaming tweets as we have reached our rate limit. This is due to making too many requests.

    Returns: False if we are sending too many tweets, otherwise return true to keep the stream going.
    """

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            logging.error(
                'Encountered error code 420. Disconnecting the stream')
            # returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False
        else:
            logging.error('Encountered error with status code: {}'.format(
                status_code))
            return True  # Don't kill the stream
```

`WS_Handler` is in charge of maintaining a list of open connections and sending any message that it receives back to every client(This behaviour is something I don't want).

```
import logging
import json
from uuid import uuid4
from tornado.web import RequestHandler
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler


class WSHandler(WebSocketHandler):

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    @property
    def sess_id(self):
        return self._sess_id

    def open(self):
        self._sess_id = uuid4().hex
        logging.debug('Connection established.')
        self.application.pc.register_websocket(self._sess_id, self)

    # When messages arrives via RabbitMQ, write it to websocket
    def on_message(self, message):
        logging.debug('Message received: {0}'.format(message))
        self.application.pc.redirect_incoming_message(
            self._sess_id, json.dumps(message))

    def on_close(self):
        logging.debug('Connection closed.')
        self.application.pc.unregister_websocket(self._sess_id)
```

The `PikaClient` module contains the PikaClient that will allows to keep track of inbound and outbound channels as well as keeping track of the websockets that currently running.

```
import logging
import pika
from constants import SETTINGS
from pika import PlainCredentials, ConnectionParameters
from pika.adapters.tornado_connection import TornadoConnection

pika.log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class PikaClient(object):
    INPUT_QUEUE_NAME = 'in_queue'

    def __init__(self):
        self.connected = False
        self.connecting = False
        self.connection = None
        self.in_channel = None
        self.out_channels = {}
        self.websockets = {}

    def connect(self):
        if self.connecting:
            return

        self.connecting = True

        # Setup rabbitMQ connection
        credentials = PlainCredentials(
            SETTINGS['RABBITMQ_USERNAME'], SETTINGS['RABBITMQ_PASSWORD'])

        param = ConnectionParameters(
            host=SETTINGS['RABBITMQ_HOST'], port=SETTINGS['RABBITMQ_PORT'], virtual_host='/', credentials=credentials)

        return TornadoConnection(param, on_open_callback=self.on_connected)

    def run(self):
        self.connection = self.connect()
        self.connection.ioloop.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.connected = False
        self.connecting = False
        self.connection.ioloop.stop()

    def on_connected(self, unused_Connection):
        self.connected = True
        self.in_channel = self.connection.channel(self.on_conn_open)

    def on_conn_open(self, channel):
        self.in_channel.exchange_declare(
            exchange='tornado_input', exchange_type='topic')
        channel.queue_declare(
            callback=self.on_input_queue_declare, queue=self.INPUT_QUEUE_NAME)

    def on_input_queue_declare(self, queue):
        self.in_channel.queue_bind(
            callback=None, exchange='tornado_input', queue=self.INPUT_QUEUE_NAME, routing_key="#")

    def register_websocket(self, sess_id, ws):
        self.websockets[sess_id] = ws
        self.create_out_channel(sess_id)

    def unregister_websocket(self, sess_id):
        self.websockets.pop(sess_id)

        if sess_id in self.out_channels:
            self.out_channels[sess_id].close()

    def create_out_channel(self, sess_id):
        def on_output_channel_creation(channel):
            def on_output_queue_declaration(queue):
                channel.basic_consume(self.on_message, queue=sess_id)

            self.out_channels[sess_id] = channel
            channel.queue_declare(callback=on_output_queue_declaration,
                                  queue=sess_id, auto_delete=True, exclusive=True)

        self.connection.channel(on_output_channel_creation)

    def redirect_incoming_message(self, sess_id, message):
        self.in_channel.basic_publish(
            exchange='tornado_input', routing_key=sess_id, body=message)

    def on_message(self, channel, method, header, body):
        sess_id = method.routing_key

        if sess_id in self.websockets:
            self.websockets[sess_id].write_message(body)
            channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        else:
            channel.basic_reject(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
```

`Server.py` is the main entry point of the application.

```
import logging
import os
from tornado import web, ioloop
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line
from client import PikaClient
from handlers import WSHandler, MainHandler

define("port", default=3000, help="run on the given port.", type=int)
define("debug", default=True, help="run in debug mode.", type=bool)


def main():
    parse_command_line()

    settings = {
        "debug": options.debug,
        "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "web/static")
    }

    app = web.Application(
        [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/stream", WSHandler),
        ],
        **settings
    )

    # Setup PikaClient
    app.pc = PikaClient()

    app.listen(options.port)
    logging.info("Server running on http://localhost:3000")

    try:
        app.pc.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        app.pc.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: If more than one people search for different keywords/topics, you'll need to cancel the already running twitter streaming request, and then resend a new request with new keywords. You'll need to store somewhere which user searched for what. When the twitter api returns a response, you can then return the requested tweets back to your users respectively.

Comment: @cures is this with a global streaming object? Because if it is, when I disconnect it will disconnect for everyone. Also all the messages will get stored in the rabbitmq queue that I mentioned. This makes it difficult to know which message belongs to who.

Comment: @xyres maybe instead of disconnecting, I can simply add the keyword to the filter and add the message that it receives in its appropriate queue. Question is how do I keep track of all the queues that are available and which message to send to which user.

Comment: You can maintain a dict of topics and map them to lists where you can keep your users based on the topic they searched for: `{"football": [user1, user2], "news": [user3, user4]}`. When twitter api returns a response, you analyze the tweets and separate them by topics. Then return the tweets back to users in each topic's list.

Comment: This is probably due to me being unfamiliar with how tornado works but when the websocket connection opens, I assign the websocket connection to a dict via a uuid4 and when the user makes a http request for a specific query, at that moment I don't know who that websocket belongs to. All I know at that point is the topic that they are searching for. The id to get that websocket is in the WShandler but tornado doesn't allow me anyway to get it. Not to mention that it creates the instance after each request. I am lost as to how I can proceed. I've updated the source as well

Comment: You need to keep the connected users in a list which is an attribute of your handler class. See [this highlighted code of a demo](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/websocket/chatdemo.py#L53-L62). The handler class has a set called `waiters` where the open connections are stored. See the `open` method, it puts the new users/connections into the `waiters` set.

Comment: @xyres Thanks, but I dont think any of this will work simply because the tweepy api doesn't tell you what the tweet is about. Even if I know that the id of this websocket is associated with this topic, there is no way for me to know in the on_status method if the message is either topic1 or topic2 unless I do some natural language processing to figure out what the message is about.