# Get tweet from keyword

Tags: twitter, stream, keyword, tweepy

I am building an app, where I have to get tweets from different keywords.
For this, I use the streamListener:

```
myStream.filter(track=['name1','name2','name3'])
```

But I have to know which tweet belongs to which keyword. Is there a way to detect this? I wanted to implement a multi stream but according to this link:
[Does Tweepy support running multiple Streams to collect data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477915/does-tweepy-support-running-multiple-streams-to-collect-data)
it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do that detection in your own code. There's nothing in the API or in the data objects returned that would indicate which filter rule the Tweet matched.